# Check size on screen doesn't work in IE - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This code apparently does not work in internet explorer? Do you know what is wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width > 1219) {
document.location = "index.php";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: What about JQuery `if ($(window).width() > 1219) {
  document.location = "index.php";
}`

Comment: Can I just add that to my code?

Comment: Yes why can't you?

Comment: Just wondered if I needed to add more to it, for it to work :-) Will try and get back to you!

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: What errors are you getting: "not working" is insufficient information for diagnosing a problem; check the browser console to see if there are any actual error messages. Also, which IE version(s) are you testing? And is it running in standards mode, compatibility mode or quirks mode? Because note that `screen.width` may not be available in older IE versions and modes, and may not work correctly in others.

Comment: Didn't work @SaucedApples :(

Comment: @Simba not quite sure as it is not on my computer the problem is. But I believe it is an older version of IE. I do not know how to show the console? I'm on a mac..

Comment: Well you need to find out those details -- ask the person reporting the problem to tell you what IE version they're using. For the browser mode, you can do a few things to force it into standard mode without having to check first. Search around here for 'quirks mode' and 'ie compatibility mode' to find out the solutions for this. Ultimately, if the user is on an old enough version of IE, you code may never work for him. If you need it to work for this user, you may find you have to rewrite it to use a more compatible method. But find out more about the user's browser before taking this step.

Comment: They are using IE 11?? @Simba